# python pandas count no order pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'v1': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e'], 
    'v2': ['b', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'c'], 
    'v3': range(0,10)})

  v1 v2  v3
0  a  b   0
1  a  b   1
2  c  d   2
3  a  b   3
4  c  d   4
5  c  e   5
6  c  d   6
7  c  d   7
8  f  g   8
9  c  e   9
```

I want to get result looks like:

```
  v1 v2  count
0  a  b      2
1  c  d      3
2  c  e      2
3  f  g      1
```

The first row `"a b 2"`, comes from `"a b"`, `"a b"`, `"b a"`. as `"a b"` **appears continuously twice, count only once.**

The second row `"c d 3"` comes from `"c d"`, `"d c"`, `"d c"`, `"c d"`, as `"d c"` appears continuously twice

The third row `"c e 2"` comes from `"c e"`, `"e c"`

The last row `"f g 1"` comes from `"f g"`

My initial thought is to use `groupby`, but I don't know how to skip the continuous appearance.

Comment: It's clear define. Why downvoted?

Comment: Probably the pictures. I removed those. By the way, you may want to add a line or two more about what you've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the first two columns, drop *consecutive* duplicates, and then count them:

```
df.iloc[:, :2] = np.sort(df.iloc[:, :2], axis=1)

m = ~df.iloc[:, :2].ne(df.iloc[:, :2].shift()).cumsum().duplicated()
df[m].groupby(['v1', 'v2'], as_index=False).count()

  v1 v2  v3
0  a  b   2
1  c  d   3
2  c  e   2
3  f  g   1
```

Answer (score 3):

### With `itertools.groupby`, `frozenset`, and `collections.Counter`

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(g[0] for g in groupby(map(frozenset, zip(df.v1, df.v2))))
pd.DataFrame([
    tuple(s) + (v,) for s, v in counts.items()
], columns='v1 v2 count'.split())

  v1 v2  count
0  b  a      2
1  c  d      3
2  c  e      2
3  g  f      1
```

---

### What's happening

- First I want to make sets out of the pairs of values in order to determine equivalence despite order.  However, `set` is not hashable and so I use `frozenset`
- Second, I use `groupby` because it chunks up my iterable by consecutivly equivalent things
- Third, I pass count how many times each unique `frozenset` occurs as the first part of the items from the `groupby`
- Fourth, I parse this result into a `DataFrame`

---

### Similar thing but using `sorted` and `tuple` instead of `frozenset`

```
pd.Series(
    Counter(g[0] for g in groupby(map(sorted, zip(df.v1, df.v2)), key=tuple))
).rename_axis(['v1', 'v2']).reset_index(name='count')

  v1 v2  count
0  a  b      2
1  c  d      3
2  c  e      2
3  f  g      1
```